# Bootstrap Carousel in Vue stops working after navigating to another route and coming back

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I'm using the Carousel from Bootstrap 5.0.2 in my (single-page) Vue 3 app. The carousel works fine when I initially open the page. However, when I navigate with the Vue router to another view and go back the Carousels automatic slide effect stops working. The controls are still working but theres just no automatic transition anymore. I can imagine that this has something to do with Vue removing the whole component from the DOM and later attaching again, but I have no idea how to fix that problem.

```html
<template>
  <div class="welcome">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel"
         data-bs-pause="false" data-bs-interval="3000" style="width: 600px" >
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="../assets/welcome_slideshow/dummy_1.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/welcome_slideshow/dummy_2.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../assets/welcome_slideshow/dummy_3.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- controls -->
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleSlidesOnly" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleSlidesOnly" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you are using BS5. I recently hit this exact issue!
Not especially a solution, but after a lot of pain

```js
  mounted () {
    // Bootstrap x Vue bug that stops the carousel working on navigating
    new bootstrap.Carousel($("#exampleSelector")).cycle()
  },
```

Whack this in your exports section.

This allows it to work every time, its a bit clumsy, but its a viable workaround for now. Know its a bit late, but saw you were the only other person suffering from this, maybe it will help someone else!

Think its an issue with Boostrap or Vue maybe both together.

Comment: I remember that after searching for a solution, I used something like a timer to initialize or restart the carousel. So it was similar to your solution but using the mounted hook should be way better than using a timer. So I will mark your answer as accepted. I would also like to mention that I rebuild the whole bootstrap carousel as a simple VUE component in the end, which was easier than expected and worked like a charm for my specific use-case.